# How can I get the Android Market installed on my Kindle Fire?

Tags: google-play-store, amazon-kindle-fire

There are a couple of apps I'd like to install that aren't available in Amazon's store. Is there a way I can get the normal Android Market app set up on this thing, so I can get apps (and updates for those apps...) without involving Amazon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Kindle Fire Utility](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1399889) to easily get root and Market with Google Apps.

It would automatically perform steps described in the above answers and even more.

Comment: Came time to do this again, and the KFU got the job done very quickly - didn't even have to install the SDK. Very nice.

Answer (score 11):

You can set up the Market on a Fire, but **only** if you have root by doing the following (guide originally from [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1351283)):

> **Prerequisites**
>
> Root your Kindle Fire
>
> Download the following apks
>   GoogleServicesFramework.apk
>   Vending.apk (Latest Version 3.3.11)
>   See [HERE](http://www.multiupload.com/DGMBZZNOXM) for .apk downloads (complete GApps zip file)
>
> Root Explorer App (or similar that lets you change ro/rw permissions)
>
> Side Loading Apps activated on Kindle Fire On the Kindle Fire Settings
>   screen, go to “Device” and turn On “Allow Installation of Application
>   From Unknown Sources”
>
> Instructions
>
> 1. Transfer the .apk files to your Kindle Fire via PC / Mac (remember where you put them)
> 2. Open Root Explorer App, and navigate to the transferred .apk files
> 3. Select the GoogleServiceFramework.apk and install
> 4. When complete, click "Done" and return to the file location for Vending.apk
> 5. Long-press Vending.apk and select the "Move" option on pop-up menu Navigate to /system/app folder
> 6. Change mount option from RO to RW (read-only to read-write) Paste Vending.apk into the /system/app folder
> 7. Long-press Vending.apk and select "Permissions" from pop-up menu Change permissions to match all other apps in this folder (rw-r--r--)
> 8. Install Vending.apk
> 9. Reboot your Kindle Fire

You can also use `adb` instead of a file manager to perform all of these steps. Simply use `adb install <apk>` to install an apk file. To move Vending.apk to `/system/app` you'd probably need to first push it to the sdcard (`adb push Vending.apk /sdcard`) and then copy it over from a root shell (`cp /sdcard/Vending.apk /system/app`). When changing permissions you would need to use `chmod 0644 /system/app/Vending.apk` from a root shell. To remount the system partition as read/write you would need to execute

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/platform/mmci-omap-hs.1/by-name/system /system
```

from a root shell.

After performing the above steps the Market won't appear in your apps list or on your carousel. You can work around this by either installing a 3rd party launcher or by using the [Market Opener app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=19427314#post19427314), which basically just bootstraps it.

Answer (score 5):

[eldarerathis's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/how-can-i-get-the-android-market-installed-on-my-kindle-fire/17345#17345) got me going on the right track... Since I already had the Android SDK installed on my Windows PC, I [configured it to recognize the Fire](http://androidforums.com/kindle-fire-all-things-root/446276-root-one-click-how-get-adb-running-root-superoneclick.html):

- Edit `<sdk location>\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf` to add the following to the `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]` sections:

  ```
  ;Kindle Fire
  %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0006
  %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0006&MI_01
  ```

  Then plug in the Kindle, and update the driver.
- Edit `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini` to add the following line:

  ```
  0x1949
  ```

  Then restart the adb server: `adb kill-server`

Then [rooted the device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/how-do-i-root-my-kindle-fire), and ran the following commands to push the market onto it:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/app/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
adb push Vending.apk /system/app/Vending.apk
```

Finally threw on that handy [Market Opener app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=19427314#post19427314) [eldarerathis pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/how-can-i-get-the-android-market-installed-on-my-kindle-fire/17345#17345), launched it, logged into my Google account, and away I went...