# How can I get the Android app store on the kindle fire?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the Android Market installed on my Kindle Fire?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/how-can-i-get-the-android-market-installed-on-my-kindle-fire)

How can I get the Android app store on the kindle fire?  Google searches for the solution seem to find [S.E.O.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) fud from Amazon.com.

Comment: It may indeed be a duplicate, however it may be helpful to keep this question with _this_ _wording_ , because searching with those terms on the magical google yielded very poor results.

Comment: That's the entire point of marking questions as duplicates - so they act as "sign posts" to other questions. I didn't say we should *delete* this.

Comment: So closed questions aren't deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to root your Kindle Fire. To do that, you'll need to follow the procedure created by Justin Case at [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/23/exclusive-how-to-easily-root-the-amazon-kindle-regardless-of-its-software-version/).

Once that's through, you've got to install the Android app store, along with all the other Google stuff it needs. You'll find those instructions [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-android-market-google-apps-on-kindle-fire/).

With that, you'll be all set. Good luck!