# Installing Android Market/Google Play on non-rooted Kindle Fire

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, amazon-kindle-fire

Is there a way to install either the Android Market or Google Play on a Kindle Fire (Android 2.3 and Kindle version 6.3.1) without first rooting it?  I have access to a Windows 7 computer with Admin privileges, but no USB cable (I do have ES File Explorer running an FTP server, so I can easily send and receive files via FileZilla on the computer).

Comment: I don't think that will work. Android has elevated permissions for system apps and I guess that Google Play needs them, so you need to install it to /system and that requires root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to root your Kindle Fire for this -- as long as the following source is still valid: [Install Android Marketplace and Google Apps on Amazon Kindle Fire](http://www.esotech.org/blog/technology/install-android-marketplace-and-google-apps-on-amazon-kindle-fire). As that howto speaks about "Android Marketplace" (and not "Google Play"), it may not be up-to-date -- but I doubt the change of the name affected the procedure of installation.

A more up-to-date tutorial is [Install Android Play Store on Amazon Kindle Fire - The Easiest Way](http://androidadvices.com/install-android-play-store-amazon-kindle-fire-easiest/), but that involves rooting the device. Maybe it has to do with the framework and a newer Android version, which makes rooting a necessary step.

**EDIT:** You may also want to take a look at these video tutorials: [How To Install Google Music / Play On Your Kindle Fire!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TcQPFHd9G4) and [GApps on Kindle Fire Without Rooting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUQC7bN1520). Looks like you can still have Google Play installed this way without rooting.

Comment: The link you gave explains that you have to root the Kindle Fire to install "Android Market."

Comment: Which link? I gave 4, and one of them even explicitly states: [GApps on Kindle Fire Without Rooting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUQC7bN1520) (Play Store is part of Google Apps/GApps). The other links are for completeness; if you use a Google Search on the topic you will find approx. 90% of the answers insist you need root. So in case the one telling otherwise does not work, the questioner can check-up the alternatives and see if they may be acceptable.

Comment: The first link. Anyway, none of the Google Apps require root, but the Play Store (it is not considered one of the Google Apps) does.

Comment: You may be right about that: I just read about the [Legacy Play Store](http://www.modaco.com/topic/356009-legacy-play-store-with-all-purchased-apps-visible/), and even that (a patched older Market-App) must be placed in the system partition, which cannot be done without root. Strange, I did not remember having my Archos rooted when I side-loaded market etc. In this case my apologies. @KevinOrr If you consider my answer inappropriate and not helpful to you, I can have it removed -- just say so. Or we can leave it stay if you think you might consider these alternatives...

Comment: @Izzy No it's good -- I just wanted to know if "there ***is*** a way", and there isn't (not without root, anyway).  So +1 to both answers but I'm accepting yours for more info.

Answer (score 4):

The necessary .apk files for Google Play Store, Services Framework, etc., must be installed in `/system/app` and doing so requires root access. So, you must root the Kindle Fire in order to do so.

However, you don't have to *leave* the Kindle Fire rooted. After you've installed it, you can always unroot the device (though I'm not sure why you'd want to do that).

Comment: IIRC you need to root the kindle fire. More information can be found at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/how-can-i-get-the-android-market-installed-on-my-kindle-fire