# google play services is not supported by kindle fire

Tags: apk, google, amazon-kindle-fire, google-play-services, amazon-kindle

I installed google play services on my kindle fire 6. Except whenever I try to launch it, it always crashes. And when I try to launch another app, YouTube for example, it says "Google Play Services, which some of your applications rely on is not supported by this device. Please contact manufacturer for more information."
I've tried rebooting, re-installing, installing another version, and installing from another website. I have google accounts and google framework apk installed. And my device is in very good condition. I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26243/1465

Comment: I tried but that post is out dated. I am using a kindle fire 6.

Comment: Did you just install the play store? If so, you need to install the framework and services. What I suggest is to uninstall it and then follow the steps <a href="http://www.epubor.com/how-to-install-google-play-on-kindle-fire.html">here</a> --- Best regards, The Doctalex

Answer (score 1):

Use [this version](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-7-0-99-1809214-038-android-apk-download/). My Fire was working perfectly until this week so the solution seems easy: to move to GPServices previous version.

Google Play services 7.0.99 (1809214-038)

Good luck.